# Object mapping JScript TestComplete

Tags: mapping, jscript, testcomplete

Is there a way to write a single function to map an object based on the type of control?

For example, I do this for a Yes button:

```
function YesBtn()  {  return Aliases.[App].Find("MappedName", "*.btnYes", 5, true);  }
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this so I can find buttons of all types using a single function, rather than mapping each button separately? This is easy enough, but if I can save space and avoid doing this for every single object, I'd prefer to do it that way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your framework makes all the `MappedName` properties have `btn` in them, then use that in your wildcard:

```
function allBtns()  {  return Aliases.[App].Find("MappedName", "*.btn*", 5, true);  }
```

Comment: Thanks, Ed. I tried that, but I ran into a problem where two OK buttons are VisibleOnScreen. For example, a question is displayed in a popup launched from the main window. Is there a way to distinguish between the two with the mapping you recommended?

Comment: Respectfully, you asked for "buttons of all types". This gives you that. Are you moving the goalposts? I would have thought the way forward is to accept this (or not), then ask a new question.